# How to stop absolute div from overflowing from parent?

Tags: css, html, layout

I have a long div inside a parent.

I think it needs to be absolutely positioned because I want to to scroll horizontally.

However I only want the section inside the parent div to be visible. I thought setting overflow: hidden on the parent would achieve this, however no such luck....

[See this js fiddle for an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/rVmDp/)

Does anyone know how to get this effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should set the parent (box1) to position:relative; 
Otherwise the box2 gets positioned relative to the body and gets outside the flow of box1.

[Editted example](http://jsfiddle.net/rVmDp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

did you try using scroll value for the overflow property.

```
overflow:scroll;
```

also remove the position element